# Phantomjs: check the image was loaded

Tags: javascript, download, phantomjs

I need to check specific image was loaded (resource has been received) and rendered correctly via img element(other content doesn't overlap img).
I've tried as follows:

```
//push query of resource failed to download into the object with url as key
page.onResourceError = function( error ){
    errors[ error.url ] = error
}

//get src of image to be checked
var src = page.evaluate(function( selector ){
    return $( selector ).attr('src');
}, selector );

//check if resource in question has failed to be downloaded
if( errors[ src ] ){
    //do stuff
}
```

Is that enough to check whether resource was downloaded? How can I get actual resource body and compare it with screenshot made by phantomjs.

Comment: Have a look at how PhantomCSS compares images using Resemble.js. If you find an answer, don't forget to post it here. You can take a screenshot of the image by using `page.render()` in conjunction with `clipRect`.